# Adding child elements to specific nodes in a force-directed graph using d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I'd like to add different child elements to my nodes depending on the node type. Therefore the node has an attribute called `type`. All nodes should consist of a `g` element with the dependent child elements.

I tried this by using D3s `filter` functionality but i'm stuck as my code doesn't add the child elements only once per node, but adds the wanted child elements multiple times (the same amount as i have nodes). So i guess i'm doing something wrong with the selection.

The nodes and links of my graph change over time, so what i did is to store the selection first and when a node gets added to `self.nodes` i call the draw function (I'll leave out the link code).

```
self.domNodes = this.svg.append('g').attr('class', 'nodes').selectAll('.node')

function draw() {
    self.domNodes = self.domNodes.data(self.nodes, (node) => node.id)
    self.domNodes.exit().remove()

    // all nodes
    self.domNodes.enter()
      .append('g')
      .attr('class', (node) => `node ${node.type}`)
      .merge(self.domNodes)

    // contributions
    self.domNodes.filter((d) => d.type === 'contribution')
      .append('circle')
      .attr('r', 4)
      .attr('fill', 'blue')

    // persons
    self.domNodes.filter((d) => d.type === 'person')
      .append('other elements and attributes...')

    self.simulation.nodes(self.nodes)
    self.simulation.force('link').links(self.links)
    self.simulation.alpha(1).restart()
}
```

What works is, that it does differentiate between `person` and `contribution` and adds the elements i want specifically for this type, but it doesn't add only one per `g` node, but it adds a multiple of those (the number of nodes i have) into every `g` node. If i keep calling the draw function it will append more and more circles to my g elements.

```
<svg>
    <g>
        <g class="nodes">
            <g class="node contribution" transform="translate(466, 442)">
                <circle r="4" fill="blue"></circle>
                <circle r="4" fill="blue"></circle>
                <circle r="4" fill="blue"></circle>
            </g>
            <g class="node contribution" transform="translate(466, 442)">
                <circle r="4" fill="blue"></circle>
                <circle r="4" fill="blue"></circle>
                <circle r="4" fill="blue"></circle>
            </g>
            <g class="node contribution" transform="translate(466, 442)">
                <circle r="4" fill="blue"></circle>
                <circle r="4" fill="blue"></circle>
                <circle r="4" fill="blue"></circle>
            </g>
            <g class="node person" transform="translate(400, 200)">
                <someotherthings></someotherthings>
                <someotherthings></someotherthings>
            </g>
            <g class="node person" transform="translate(400, 200)">
                <someotherthings></someotherthings>
                <someotherthings></someotherthings>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

What am i doing wrong here? I only want the `circle` and other elements only append once per node.

```
<svg>
    <g>
        <g class="nodes">
            <g class="node contribution" transform="translate(466, 442)">
                <circle r="4" fill="blue"></circle>
            </g>
            <g class="node contribution" transform="translate(466, 442)">
                <circle r="4" fill="blue"></circle>
            </g>
            <g class="node contribution" transform="translate(466, 442)">
                <circle r="4" fill="blue"></circle>
            </g>
            <g class="node person" transform="translate(400, 200)">
                <someotherthings></someotherthings>
            </g>
            <g class="node person" transform="translate(400, 200)">
                <someotherthings></someotherthings>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your particular problem, but have you seen [*"How to create SVG elements of different types based on data?"*](/q/39278704)?

Comment: Posted an answer, please have a look. If it doesn't work, please help me with a link to problem replicated on fiddler/plunker.

Comment: Do the multiple child nodes appear the first time you call `draw()` - or do you have to call it more than once for nodes to appear (initially) or for multiple child nodes to be present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading [selection.data](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_data) on the d3 wiki again, i finally got it working.

I merged my notes beforehand, so my selection included the enter and update nodes. What i did now was first to create the enter nodes, then do the selections and filters on them and merge them afterwards.

```
function draw() {
    self.domNodes = self.domNodes.data(self.nodes, (node) => node.id)
    self.domNodes.exit().remove()

    // all nodes
    const enterNodes = self.domNodes.enter()
      .append('g')
      .attr('class', (node) => `node ${node.type}`)

    // contributions
    enterNodes.filter((d) => d.type === 'contribution')
      .append('circle')
      .attr('r', 4)
      .attr('fill', 'blue')

    // persons
    enterNodes.filter((d) => d.type === 'person')
      .append('other elements and attributes...')

    self.domNodes = self.domNodes.merge(enterNodes)

    self.simulation.nodes(self.nodes)
    self.simulation.force('link').links(self.links)
    self.simulation.alpha(1).restart()
}
```